# using another function variable with matchNr variable

Tags: jmeter

I have implemented a regular expression extractor with a negative match no. Now I want to use this variable with another variable, e.g.: `${story_matchNr_${__counter(TRUE,)}}` as I am using this inside a loop controller and hence want every `matchNr` value in single request.

I tried using eval function or user-defined variable as well, but it seems we cant use any variable of functions with this variable.

Is there any simpler method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to get this done:

1. Using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) functon which allows combining 2 variables
2. Using [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) which gives more options of variables concatenation and control

Links above contain examples and sample use cases.

Answer (score -1):

I had tried beanshell as well but could nt implement it to my use ,though i finally got it working with "For Each Controller" after correlation which proved to be very simple and worked smoothly :)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.